# NodeJS: Hash sha512 in raw binary (convert from PHP)

Tags: php, node.js, sha512

In my PHP app I have a function which hashes a string like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$hash = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';

for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    $hash = hash('sha512', $hash, true);
}

$hash = hash('sha512', $hash, false);

echo $hash;
echo "\n";
```

The sample code above returns

`82a58adbbe7388444507b84f9dc93fd54825c514059d4b698415444ee924e2eb5609941ca4f03e246f9eeae74180298a8a02623698983de14852a8fb88868b9e`

I need to move the app from PHP to NodeJS, so I rewrite the above code like this

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

var hash = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';

for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    hash = crypto.createHash('sha512').update(hash).digest('binary');
}

hash = crypto.createHash('sha512').update(hash).digest('hex');

console.log(hash);
```

But I get a different result

`684806a7c59ba904dceebf5e286077aa59157b945e5302c7a268f03505b615879bf6f7264e82b2f0969fd317e7ce5d39a1b05978be96819f9a1fa837a329bbd2`

The problem seems coming from the binary part. If I just hash text, I get the same result for both.

If you know where the problem is please let me know. Thanks!

**EDIT**: The PHP code can't be changed, it is the code of a working PHP app and I need to convert the app to Node JS and stuck at this binary issue.

Comment: Probably encoding issues. Do you need to digest the first step as binary?

Comment: @wroniasty If I do that, it just creates another different hash.

Comment: works for me just fine

Comment: @wroniasty Please post an answer with your code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. There is no "binary" encoding. I had created binary the wrong way. Here is the working code:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

var hash = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';


for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    hash = crypto.createHash('sha512').update(hash).digest('hex');
    hash = new Buffer(hash, "hex");
}

hash = crypto.createHash('sha512').update(hash).digest('hex');

console.log(hash);
```

Result:

`82a58adbbe7388444507b84f9dc93fd54825c514059d4b698415444ee924e2eb5609941ca4f03e246f9eeae74180298a8a02623698983de14852a8fb88868b9e`

Comment: `digest()` always returns `Buffer`. You don't need to encode to `hex` and then convert back to `Buffer`.

Answer (score 0):

Works just fine. Removed the loop cause I'm working in a console.

```
var hash = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';     
hash = crypto.createHash('sha512').update(hash).digest('hex');
hash = crypto.createHash('sha512').update(hash).digest('hex'); 
hash = crypto.createHash('sha512').update(hash).digest('hex');
hash = crypto.createHash('sha512').update(hash).digest('hex');
hash = crypto.createHash('sha512').update(hash).digest('hex');
console.log(hash)
```

eb6301ffb2ed389cb952e6d6c22f9c13d015f4de0c6807852acc0b005bd36002d772d8766842909efac9c9feedd2e69b105f2b7394424316f9027c80df8df0b4

```
$hash = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
$hash = hash('sha512', $hash, false)
$hash = hash('sha512', $hash, false)
$hash = hash('sha512', $hash, false)
$hash = hash('sha512', $hash, false)
$hash = hash('sha512', $hash, false)
echo $hash;
```

eb6301ffb2ed389cb952e6d6c22f9c13d015f4de0c6807852acc0b005bd36002d772d8766842909efac9c9feedd2e69b105f2b7394424316f9027c80df8df0b4

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however you can not disable raw binary in PHP code, it should always be ```$hash = hash('sha512', $hash, true)```. I am trying to make NodeJS version works the same to the original PHP version.

Comment: If we do that the result of NodeJS app is not the same to the result of PHP app. NodeJS app can't read/work with the old result which PHP app generated in the past.